# overwrite permission for .mycshrc in linux

Tags: linux, terminal

I am trying to edit my `.mycshrc` file to add in more shortcut commands in my terminal.
However, I realize there is a problem.

1. It appears that my file was replaced by a senior (he is gone, the same goes to the computer) and I am unable to edit it due to the permission rights where the options in the Permissions tab are all greyed out.
   I tried typing `chmod 644 .mycshrc` and I was given the error: chmod: changing permissions of `.mycshrc': Operation not permitted`
2. Then I tried to create a new plain text document file, rename it as `.mycshrc` and it ain't working even as I have added in new commands unless I am doing it wrong..

The following is a sample that I am trying to add it in:

```
alias designer '/apps/Linux64/qt/qt-4.5.0/bin/designer'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the user, and not the file mode in this case. Use

```
sudo chown youruser:youruser .mycshrc
```

where `youruser` is your username.

In any case, the `chmod 644 .mycshrc` was failing because you aren't the owner of the file (the senior's user account is the owner most probably since he replaced it). That is precisely the reason why you need to do the above step with `sudo`, as the `root` user.

Comment: The important bit here is that you have to do it as user 'root', thus the `sudo`...

Comment: @arkascha Added the same :)

Comment: I was given the following error while executing it.. chown: invalid group: tht:tht'` no matter which username i put it in... I have made sure that I am in the directory as I execute the code.. Even as I put is as one username, it seems to work? but it is still not executing my alias - designer.. Would it be a better idea if i just create a whole new file? –

Comment: @user3212246 After adding the new alias, did you open a new terminal window to check out the alias?

Comment: Prior to what I have answered, I deleted the file, created a new one with the same name along with the new alias added in. I need to run `source ~/.mycshrc` so that it will works

Comment: @user3212246 Opening the new terminal window automatically re-sources the file, and that is what I had meant to tell. I should have been more explicit though :)

Answer (score 0):

Find out a easier way to handle the problem I am facing.

- Delete away the old file
- Create a new file (make sure file format is the same as the old one)
  Add in any new alias if necessary
- type `source ~/.mycshrc` in command line
- Viola~ It works!

Make sure you are in the directory when the file is being saved since it works for me in this manner